# How do I make an array of matrices in R, like the data from dataset_mnist()? (keras)

Tags: r, arrays, keras, matrix, mnist

I want to make my own array of (N x N) matrices that matches the keras-compatible format  that is loaded with `dataset_mnist()`. As

```
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
x_train <- mnist$train$x
str (x_train)
```

yields

```
int [1:60000, 1:28, 1:28] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I want to make  my own data in this format. Let's say I have 2000 different 100x100 matrices of integers: mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4... mat2000.
How can I combine them to produce an object with the structure:

```
int [1:2000, 1:100, 1:100] ...
```

that I can then use as input data for keras models?

I've tried:

```
as.vector (c(mat1, mat2))
as.array (c(mat1, mat2))
rbind (mat1, mat2)
```

But it does not produce the correctly structured data.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`c`oncatenate your matrices and make `array`. Also `c`oncatenate matrix dimension and third `dim`ension, which is the number of matrices. *Example:*

```
m1 <- matrix(1, 2, 3)
m2 <- matrix(2, 2, 3)
m3 <- matrix(3, 2, 3)

array(c(m1, m2, m3), c(dim(m1), 3))
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    2    2
# [2,]    2    2    2
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    3    3
# [2,]    3    3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look the package listarrays.

```
m <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
listarrays::bind_as_rows(m, m, m) |> str()
# int [1:3, 1:2, 1:2] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
```